# Error using inverse gaussian distribution with glmer

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a model and even after searching through my other forums, I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

Here's a histogram to show why I'm using the inverse.gaussian family.

[image]

Here is my code for fitting the model:

```
glm.full.odba  <- glmer(meanodba ~ AirTemp + LagAir + Radiation + Windspeed + LagRadiation + 
        + Precip + Raining + LULC + Elevation + (1 | Turtle),
      data = na.omit(odba_fit_data_set), 
      family = inverse.gaussian(link='inverse'))
```

Here is my data.

```
> 
> dput(odba_fit_data_set[150:300,])
structure(list(Turtle = c("R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12"), LULC = c(41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 81L, 41L, 81L, 41L, 81L, 41L, 81L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L), meanodba = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.0024429845, 0.0024429845, 0.002844277, 
0.002844277, 0.0701741105, 0.0701741105, 0.003012713, 0.003012713, 
0.168142569, 0.168142569, 0.19269525, 0.19269525, 0.003600107, 
0.003600107, 0.003282639, 0.003282639, 0.006676893, 0.006676893, 
0.004318509, 0.004318509, 0.0049651105, 0.0049651105, 0.052186496, 
0.052186496, 0.002547072, 0.002547072, 0.003099685, 0.003099685, 
0.006663461, 0.006663461, 0.002233525, 0.002233525, 0.002393341, 
0.002393341, 0.003468077, 0.003468077, 0.001722613, 0.001722613, 
0.002360538, 0.002360538, 0.006206355, 0.006206355, 0.002143561, 
0.002143561, 0.001891434, 0.001891434, 0.00230823, 0.00230823, 
0.002935105, 0.002935105, 0.00518635, 0.00518635, 0.016733862, 
0.016733862, 0.002794176, 0.002794176, 0.0095226515, 0.0095226515, 
0.002396399, 0.002396399, 0.002252792, 0.002252792, 0.034889546, 
0.034889546, 0.001938629, 0.001938629, 0.002258683, 0.002258683, 
0.001835079, 0.001835079, 0.002609543, 0.002609543, 0.0026749535, 
0.0026749535, 0.004785412, 0.004785412, 0.0476675725, 0.0476675725, 
0.002130554, 0.002130554, 0.020104818, 0.020104818, 0.002233463, 
0.002233463, 0.00265004, 0.00265004, 0.002577044, 0.002577044, 
0.001952181, 0.001952181, 0.002061738, 0.002061738, 0.002173133, 
0.002173133, 0.002588346, 0.002588346, 0.001712986, 0.001712986, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Elevation = c(NA, NA, NA, 282.27, 283.96, 282.27, 283.96, 
282.27, 283.96, 282.27, 283.96, 283.21, 284.28, 283.21, 284.28, 
283.21, 284.28, 283.21, 284.28, 282.14, 283.96, 282.14, 283.96, 
282.14, 283.96, 282.14, 283.96, 281.63, 284.46, 281.63, 284.46, 
281.63, 284.46, 281.63, 284.46, 281.63, 284.22, 281.63, 284.22, 
281.63, 284.22, 281.63, 284.22, 281.63, 284.22, 281.63, 284.22, 
281.63, 284.22, 281.63, 284.22, 282.63, 284.28, 282.63, 284.28, 
282.63, 284.28, 282.63, 284.28, 281.63, 284.6, 281.63, 284.6, 
281.63, 284.6, 281.63, 284.6, 282.14, 284.4, 282.14, 284.4, 282.14, 
284.4, 282.14, 284.4, 281.63, 284.4, 281.63, 284.4, 281.63, 284.4, 
281.63, 284.4, 282.14, 284.4, 282.14, 284.4, 282.14, 284.4, 282.14, 
284.4, 281.36, 284.28, 281.36, 284.28, 281.36, 284.28, 281.36, 
284.28, 282.14, 284.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Radiation = c(-0.597405546493466, 
-0.301272695347495, -0.302040941158138, -0.0681408493951469, 
-0.0727447343846593, 0.398122842509549, 0.385847679162298, 0.078060477727512, 
0.0710511918970137, 0.0108868949954796, 0.00498279333516397, 
0.117574349922825, 0.109914955756925, 0.0701577032884494, 0.0632784391250314, 
0.283532613143141, 0.273142763968554, 1.00268508709784, 0.980463266218946, 
1.23186554583066, 1.20587309660643, 1.01453924875644, 0.992122395376919, 
0.836726823877526, 0.817235458007317, 0.797212951682213, 0.778371694147405, 
0.342803421436111, 0.331438409758422, 0.330949259777517, 0.319779280600448, 
1.19235167363534, 1.16700933274652, 0.824872662218932, 0.805576328849343, 
0.354657583094705, 0.343097538916395, 0.8209212749994, 0.801689952463352, 
2.40147616281193, 2.35624050685982, 2.75710101256975, 2.70601438159902, 
2.26712899734786, 2.22410370973612, 2.65436494486193, 2.60496859556325, 
2.37381645227521, 2.32903587215788, 2.21180957627443, 2.16969444033224, 
1.46499739178301, 1.43516930337991, 2.12092767022521, 2.08030778345444, 
1.85618472651661, 1.81992056559304, 2.17624709129864, 2.13471705285832, 
2.16834431685958, 2.12694430008634, 2.3856706139338, 2.34069500131585, 
2.19995541461583, 2.15803531117427, 1.86013611373614, 1.82380694197903, 
2.32639980564083, 2.28239935552598, 2.14068460632286, 2.0997396653844, 
2.22366373793302, 2.18135356949022, 2.11697628300567, 2.07642140706845, 
1.88779582427286, 1.85101157668097, 1.71788617383301, 1.68389739208335, 
1.5400737489541, 1.50901045471374, 1.41758074514863, 1.38853278674802, 
1.23186554583066, 1.20587309660643, 1.04219895929315, 1.01932703007886, 
0.864386534414245, 0.844440092709255, 0.67076856065721, 0.654007649795688, 
0.413928391387674, 0.401393184706263, 0.0741090905079807, 0.0671648155110226, 
-0.0246755899803023, -0.0299945941387565, -0.210390789298274, 
-0.212654284280341, -0.234099112615462, -0.235972542596288, -0.522550379641249, 
-0.519678018773643, -0.609480898470938, -0.605178299265449, -0.668751706763908, 
-0.663473945055316, -0.716168353398284, -0.71011046168721, -0.739876676715471, 
-0.733428720003157, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148), LagRadiation = c(-0.64404206312536, -0.601578124031875, 
-0.597405546493466, -0.301272695347495, -0.302040941158138, -0.0681408493951469, 
-0.0727447343846593, 0.398122842509549, 0.385847679162298, 0.078060477727512, 
0.0710511918970137, 0.0108868949954796, 0.00498279333516397, 
0.117574349922825, 0.109914955756925, 0.0701577032884494, 0.0632784391250314, 
0.283532613143141, 0.273142763968554, 1.00268508709784, 0.980463266218946, 
1.23186554583066, 1.20587309660643, 1.01453924875644, 0.992122395376919, 
0.836726823877526, 0.817235458007317, 0.797212951682213, 0.778371694147405, 
0.342803421436111, 0.331438409758422, 0.330949259777517, 0.319779280600448, 
1.19235167363534, 1.16700933274652, 0.824872662218932, 0.805576328849343, 
0.354657583094705, 0.343097538916395, 0.8209212749994, 0.801689952463352, 
2.40147616281193, 2.35624050685982, 2.75710101256975, 2.70601438159902, 
2.26712899734786, 2.22410370973612, 2.65436494486193, 2.60496859556325, 
2.37381645227521, 2.32903587215788, 2.21180957627443, 2.16969444033224, 
1.46499739178301, 1.43516930337991, 2.12092767022521, 2.08030778345444, 
1.85618472651661, 1.81992056559304, 2.17624709129864, 2.13471705285832, 
2.16834431685958, 2.12694430008634, 2.3856706139338, 2.34069500131585, 
2.19995541461583, 2.15803531117427, 1.86013611373614, 1.82380694197903, 
2.32639980564083, 2.28239935552598, 2.14068460632286, 2.0997396653844, 
2.22366373793302, 2.18135356949022, 2.11697628300567, 2.07642140706845, 
1.88779582427286, 1.85101157668097, 1.71788617383301, 1.68389739208335, 
1.5400737489541, 1.50901045471374, 1.41758074514863, 1.38853278674802, 
1.23186554583066, 1.20587309660643, 1.04219895929315, 1.01932703007886, 
0.864386534414245, 0.844440092709255, 0.67076856065721, 0.654007649795688, 
0.413928391387674, 0.401393184706263, 0.0741090905079807, 0.0671648155110226, 
-0.0246755899803023, -0.0299945941387565, -0.210390789298274, 
-0.212654284280341, -0.234099112615462, -0.235972542596288, -0.522550379641249, 
-0.519678018773643, -0.609480898470938, -0.605178299265449, -0.668751706763908, 
-0.663473945055316, -0.716168353398284, -0.71011046168721, -0.739876676715471, 
-0.733428720003157, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148), 
    AirTemp = c(-1.06888515955184, -0.884644073243182, -0.826648603212786, 
    -0.640333340558809, -0.586334559225632, -0.511337273701461, 
    -0.459448744000414, -0.411658494766236, -0.361400614053654, 
    -0.439021296826886, -0.388315786980216, -0.397977093735911, 
    -0.347943027590374, -0.333479060307237, -0.284500119977765, 
    -0.268981026878563, -0.221057212365156, -0.0539875821163153, 
    -0.00958085365646016, 0.211822495044282, 0.251880826201564, 
    0.342773047763106, 0.380689153778679, 0.479587058066354, 
    0.515265018411486, 0.50890434598848, 0.544102703689945, 0.585129294586003, 
    0.619080685413937, 0.551903034940929, 0.586397975431684, 
    0.540176119772079, 0.5748629013203, 0.608583124923703, 0.642150833636704, 
    0.46590565703603, 0.501807431948205, 0.546039577356504, 0.580630438375992, 
    0.669172186629427, 0.701748716545518, 0.911528433452325, 
    0.940140248180776, 1.0307520710023, 1.05741350164651, 1.08743216098507, 
    1.11316635985153, 1.19688336922767, 1.22082705155777, 1.21447374198095, 
    1.23812966272485, 1.24379102990307, 1.26696734800331, 1.2496544874875, 
    1.272734885059, 1.29265317643995, 1.31503015680074, 1.37278709676042, 
    1.39385316322852, 1.36106018159157, 1.38231808911714, 1.49201073431039, 
    1.51112641669426, 1.48223830500302, 1.50151385493477, 1.52132802223252, 
    1.53996410197271, 1.53891839498579, 1.55726671313979, 1.55455428187759, 
    1.57264681195497, 1.60341642841447, 1.6207096207524, 1.64055165978249, 
    1.65723735543845, 1.61905231530627, 1.63608971956758, 1.62296128702922, 
    1.63993474427137, 1.62882474461364, 1.64570228132706, 1.62491577289069, 
    1.64185725662327, 1.66205100425872, 1.67838499130932, 1.62882474461364, 
    1.64570228132706, 1.61514334358332, 1.63224469486378, 1.57214465463087, 
    1.58994942312204, 1.55455428187759, 1.57264681195497, 1.49982867775629, 
    1.51881646610184, 1.43337615846614, 1.45345104613734, 1.36887812503747, 
    1.39000813852473, 1.33956083711535, 1.36117045324627, 1.27897177540962, 
    1.30157257033746, 1.16561159544407, 1.19006685392742, 1.08156870340065, 
    1.10739882279584, 1.01707066997197, 1.04395591518323, 0.946709178958875, 
    0.974745470514926, 0.866575258638401, 0.895922464087139, 
    0.811849654517101, 0.842092118234016, 0.749306106949902, 
    0.780571722973305, 0.590992752170428, 0.624848222469629, 
    0.557766492525354, 0.592165512487376, 0.497177430819629, 
    0.532567629578561, 0.448315284282755, 0.48450482078113, 0.356454448793431, 
    0.39414674024196, 0.248957726412307, 0.288408560887612, 0.176641749537732, 
    0.217275603867414, 0.118007173693484, 0.159600233310497, 
    0.317364731563931, 0.355696493204016, 0.307592302256556, 
    0.346083931444529, 0.260684641581156, 0.299943634998995, 
    0.250912212273782, 0.290331073239509, 0.247003240550832, 
    0.286486048535714, 0.260684641581156, 0.299943634998995, 
    0.290001929503282, 0.328781320277454, 0.270457070888531, 
    0.309556196758481, 0.282183986057382, 0.321091270869865), 
    LagAir = c(-1.15111030880199, -1.13781139154986, -1.07614378044101, 
    -0.89150203046162, -0.833944227274796, -0.647147505572498, 
    -0.5936668927845, -0.518128316431041, -0.466800460173624, 
    -0.418431670276279, -0.368767307701583, -0.445799377063861, 
    -0.395678369164496, -0.404747816882488, -0.355311776970126, 
    -0.34023822231176, -0.291878560664688, -0.275728627741031, 
    -0.22844534435925, -0.0606966458386043, -0.0170012900077894, 
    0.205161077240761, 0.244420449917653, 0.336135102581331, 
    0.373209101204452, 0.472973636519239, 0.507764408519017, 
    0.502296179505934, 0.536597688657853, -1.30006279607623, 
    -1.23568793054257, 0.545302575886419, 0.578886499528145, 
    0.533573558691741, 0.567353187472611, 0.601992825660695, 
    0.634630841129894, 0.459289783125448, 0.494308877787561, 
    0.53943806728908, 0.573119843500378, 0.662592747833198, 0.694219620083487, 
    0.904992436523207, 0.932574735897861, 1.0242374446691, 1.04983007512913, 
    1.08092769444337, 1.10557441673087, 1.1903985215937, 1.21321866258253, 
    1.20799204738572, 1.23051863066583, 1.23731459037241, 1.25935191080466, 
    1.24317909896975, 1.26511856683243, 1.28618549535024, 1.30740737770272, 
    1.36633377951387, 1.38621834341554, 1.35460476231919, 1.37468503136001, 
    1.48557878765976, 1.5034736826468, 1.4758046066642, 1.49386258926719, 
    1.51490133064646, 1.53230696278564, 1.53249485643847, 1.54960693086894, 
    1.54813354603138, 1.56498468027632, 1.5970044510092, 1.61304014717438, 
    1.63414633879235, 1.6495623020169, 1.61264314060211, 1.62841789658176, 
    1.61655281300033, 1.6322623339336, 1.62241732159767, 1.63802898996137, 
    1.61850764919944, 1.63418455260953, 1.65564953698259, 1.67070670745205, 
    1.62241732159767, 1.63802898996137, 1.60873346820388, 1.62457345922991, 
    1.56572707182339, 1.58228464835962, 1.54813354603138, 1.56498468027632, 
    1.49339813245621, 1.51116255735049, 1.42693370168637, 1.44580712236913, 
    1.36242410711564, 1.3823739060637, 1.33310156412895, 1.35354062592486, 
    1.27250164195645, 1.29395184697127, 1.15912114240789, 1.18246316376777, 
    1.07506318584604, 1.09980776070311, -1.41930780422212, -1.35294326977384, 
    0.940179488107241, 0.967174672064464, 0.860031203943609, 
    0.888363706351646, 0.805295790368445, 0.83454158342582, 0.74274103199683, 
    0.773030585796304, 0.584399299868679, 0.617330873046592, 
    0.551167084483758, 0.584653155555912, 0.490567162311256, 
    0.525064376602319, 0.441696257333431, 0.477008909704259, 
    0.349818955975121, 0.386664631935908, 0.242302965023907, 
    0.280942604760178, 0.169974025656727, 0.20982051375105, 0.111328939683338, 
    0.15215395347338, 0.310722231992862, 0.348220258417461, 0.300948050997297, 
    0.338609165037849, 0.254031982218585, 0.292475916815712, 
    0.619586351452712, 0.651930809213195, 0.240348128824794, 
    0.279020386084255, 0.254031982218585, 0.292475916815712, 
    0.28335452520528, 0.321309196954548, 0.26380616321415, 0.302087010195324
    ), Windspeed = c(-1.05571268366963, -1.13062286302055, -1.13344227864813, 
    -0.657558586537914, -0.659998381960915, -0.392462865795273, 
    -0.394689929678934, -0.314795596522005, -0.316960334700436, 
    -0.415570483099716, -0.417816090168405, -0.60107329979372, 
    -0.603467767431099, -0.83471698587198, -0.837298945713522, 
    -0.400807283155211, -0.403041043189021, -0.150474762357074, 
    -0.152507637886424, 0.552381930653077, 0.550913077001637, 
    0.77382992982066, 0.772538781692396, 0.729540329987143, 0.728213640754244, 
    0.419513131152528, 0.417937654187182, 0.426573791995553, 
    0.425003981003409, 0.418229374635615, 0.416652867493322, 
    0.577415182732891, 0.575966417531897, 1.00490610286509, 1.0038003865871, 
    0.303333166371855, 0.301664458392899, 0.436201965872404, 
    0.434639881207355, 0.567145130597583, 0.565688123981021, 
    0.810416990552695, 0.809155202467391, 0.587043356609743, 
    0.585602317735843, 1.09926220685824, 1.09823220858577, 0.785383738472881, 
    0.784101861937131, 0.885516746792136, 0.88431522405817, 0.947137059603985, 
    0.945984985363425, 1.0151761550004, 1.01407868013798, 1.24689420630329, 
    1.24598267837961, 1.41314067524359, 1.41236255523441, 1.40800564917594, 
    1.40722340845897, 1.19618582388521, 1.19523360397216, 1.24881984107866, 
    1.2479098584204, 1.40158686659137, 1.40079947498968, 1.43111326648038, 
    1.43034956894845, 1.68658081334617, 1.68602212102648, 1.57296836159933, 
    1.57231849861992, 1.55756328339636, 1.5569010582936, 1.77901128256395, 
    1.77852676298436, 1.7841463086316, 1.7836659097598, 1.85603667357876, 
    1.85561396461593, 1.61083917884827, 1.61021970608877, 1.34831097113946, 
    1.34748082719451, 1.51776683137204, 1.51707267078396, 1.75847117829333, 
    1.75797017588261, 1.86630672571406, 1.86589225816681, 1.22250283248193, 
    1.22157173119628, 1.3284127451273, 1.32756663343969, 1.36820919715162, 
    1.36739502094933, 0.906056851062752, 0.904871811159921, 1.07936398084608, 
    1.07831801483095, 0.992710415954415, 0.991594912995436, 0.403466174691109, 
    0.401877820513938, 0.428499426770923, 0.426931161044198, 
    0.658291843298443, 0.656907979245043, 0.424006278961726, 
    0.42243440761569, 0.31231946199025, 0.310657965249916, 0.379716679128209, 
    0.378109266677538, 0.155059288668343, 0.15327159525213, -0.456008813382492, 
    -0.458286871024978, -0.223648883821145, -0.225740479436414, 
    -0.4425293699549, -0.444796610739454, -0.501582169732922, 
    -0.503896798656989, -0.400807283155211, -0.403041043189021, 
    -0.224290762079602, -0.226382872783344, -0.299390518319043, 
    -0.301542894374123, 0.0594194281582861, 0.0575549865595997, 
    0.338636470586977, 0.336996092474035, 0.171748123388219, 
    0.169973822272303, 0.094722732373408, 0.0928866206407353, 
    0.0196229761339671, 0.0177265990499562, 0.145431114791492, 
    0.143635695048184, 0.146714871308406, 0.144920481742044, 
    0.354683427048396, 0.353055926147278, 0.242996610076919, 
    0.241279483781504, 0.232726557941611, 0.231001190230628), 
    LagWind = c(-1.4482150186437, -1.05281418763603, -1.05571268366963, 
    -1.13047505396601, -1.13344227864813, -0.657449777228888, 
    -0.659998381960915, -0.39237591116046, -0.394689929678934, 
    -0.314715044830485, -0.316960334700436, -0.415481623456982, 
    -0.417816090168405, -0.600969147170724, -0.603467767431099, 
    -0.83459357150222, -0.837298945713522, -0.400719640600871, 
    -0.403041043189021, -0.150407757388554, -0.152507637886424, 
    0.552390991630642, 0.550913077001637, 0.773820734472306, 
    0.772538781692396, 0.729534785903973, 0.728213640754244, 
    0.419533145925643, 0.417937654187182, 0.426593224682913, 
    0.425003981003409, 0.418249495242503, 0.416652867493322, 
    0.577422179951873, 0.575966417531897, 1.00487785743752, 1.0038003865871, 
    0.303362759101465, 0.301664458392899, 0.436220604806464, 
    0.434639881207355, 0.567152974486753, 0.565688123981021, 
    0.810404778941799, 0.809155202467391, 0.587049560075424, 
    0.585602317735843, 1.09922618264832, 1.09823220858577, 0.785373590620567, 
    0.784101861937131, 0.885498343905494, 0.88431522405817, 0.947113576696218, 
    0.945984985363425, 1.01514706290264, 1.01407868013798, 1.24684601120943, 
    1.24598267837961, 1.41307877467607, 1.41236255523441, 1.40794417194351, 
    1.40722340845897, 1.19614180922539, 1.19523360397216, 1.24877148723414, 
    1.2479098584204, 1.40152591852781, 1.40079947498968, 1.43104988424003, 
    1.43034956894845, 1.68649637018491, 1.68602212102648, 1.57289328472701, 
    1.57231849861992, 1.55748947652933, 1.5569010582936, 1.77891921937099, 
    1.77852676298436, 1.78405382210355, 1.7836659097598, 1.8559382603594, 
    1.85561396461593, 1.61076097987964, 1.61021970608877, 1.34825441517749, 
    1.34748082719451, 1.51769630535199, 1.51707267078396, 1.75838080844075, 
    1.75797017588261, 1.86620746582452, 1.86589225816681, 1.22245664822977, 
    1.22157173119628, 1.32835782958882, 1.32756663343969, 1.36815100076617, 
    1.36739502094933, 0.906036754835735, 0.904871811159921, 1.07932959705965, 
    1.07831801483095, 0.992683175947691, 0.991594912995436, 0.403487512386392, 
    0.401877820513938, 0.428518700707624, 0.426931161044198, 
    0.658292172989699, 0.656907979245043, 0.424025923316633, 
    0.42243440761569, 0.312348313883446, 0.310657965249916, 0.3797399747483, 
    0.378109266677538, 0.155101105198786, 0.15327159525213, -0.455916619975895, 
    -0.458286871024978, -0.223575846327539, -0.225740479436414, 
    -0.442438287802924, -0.444796610739454, -0.501486219227368, 
    -0.503896798656989, -0.400719640600871, -0.403041043189021, 
    -0.224217671669109, -0.226382872783344, -0.299311236632804, 
    -0.301542894374123, 0.0594691293048493, 0.0575549865595997, 
    0.338663152887818, 0.336996092474035, 0.171788564079607, 
    0.169973822272303, 0.0947695230912017, 0.0928866206407353, 
    0.0196759581275068, 0.0177265990499562, 0.145473725075235, 
    0.143635695048184, 0.146757375758375, 0.144920481742044, 
    0.354708786427069, 0.353055926147278, 0.243031176993881, 
    0.241279483781504), Precip = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Raining = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), LogBT = c(2.64513406688667, 
    2.59256452449451, 2.64219525830619, 2.69063272706514, 2.64811145513026, 
    2.6095794764782, 2.63769926500569, 2.63385333610875, 2.64219525830619, 
    2.67926199076733, 2.64808785992953, 2.82300454843136, 2.69291400240597, 
    2.80044705036818, 2.66859301554709, 2.83409530795287, 2.68296028737597, 
    2.8462844070338, 2.69856087508109, 3.00284028501337, 2.75059870434817, 
    2.84991620857235, 2.7235297719506, 2.87139656595869, 2.73579506141077, 
    2.9861700340503, 2.75191821844772, 3.13182081056284, 2.83493734730432, 
    3.12176268737869, 2.79620351842232, 3.14357740081797, 2.82510210534962, 
    3.1453584475098, 2.84227024544059, 3.14087103922023, 2.89674032434704, 
    3.13091854610906, 2.87929208587355, 3.12544388007565, 2.8863079562727, 
    3.1480527080751, 2.90361698464619, 3.28571170505446, 2.9472595589921, 
    3.14537279790336, 2.91838315712639, 3.18838912559666, 2.93071363717954, 
    3.28182558459247, 2.94946143322156, 3.44722181997343, 3.3078264314472, 
    3.42035710081212, 3.07551340855884, 3.46366083466759, 3.24665958987969, 
    3.47661402094691, 3.37641504282428, 3.38502283159387, 3.41270864983416, 
    3.44656370174316, 3.45105575815838, 3.41146669353866, 3.42903950089024, 
    3.37510434449042, 3.40721258731694, 3.26127098132008, 3.38772931527041, 
    3.30425809781036, 3.40584213363708, 3.27475193542712, 3.42633433996079, 
    3.25002559386042, 3.41134571271397, 3.16755445991124, 3.35120149089647, 
    3.19694373186846, 3.36279144759733, 3.17453375325079, 3.3678359139999, 
    3.15430174754296, 3.35483925768401, 3.06212844319367, 3.27621348190239, 
    3.10133775920422, 3.31932429616501, 3.06797541274899, 3.29258466976219, 
    3.04442719509275, 3.26672586471954, 2.99454823952895, 3.18738515777683, 
    3.00803956057604, 3.21872914744493, 2.99559893133098, 3.19765218841657, 
    2.98721275193825, 3.17874803377742, 2.96596011522032, 3.11792040731808, 
    2.97346962288, 3.14341925145276, 2.96812123984581, 3.12711135161037, 
    2.96382872454098, 3.11237391732968, 2.94313989010148, 3.06194127366433, 
    2.95298133648636, 3.08317827830151, 2.94753943095251, 3.06972595346232, 
    2.9420677489683, 3.05704685337308, 2.91303883356946, 3.011933652892, 
    2.92652509339029, 3.03122810923883, 2.91980469820808, 3.01907438112691, 
    2.90962957450058, 3.00780905477944, 2.88080764874609, 2.97213947261567, 
    2.89244368404806, 2.98801927134683, 2.88429779310769, 2.97958595381129, 
    2.87728651834751, 2.97000412498126, 2.85353486784419, 2.93847385471371, 
    2.86191512581965, 2.95162363392793, 2.85591449628676, 2.94398273475191, 
    2.85111104394286, 2.93513265142506, 2.83409530795287, 2.90817529320446, 
    2.84022790011906, 2.92064946742964, 2.83656067665874, 2.91273102705058, 
    2.83162384617939, 2.90591696923163, 2.81929337991819, 2.88861094932297, 
    2.82547761797817, 2.89558039160355)), row.names = 150:300, class = "data.frame")
```

And lastly, here is the error I get.

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
  PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value
```

I'm really struggling here. If someone could propose a simple answer to fix this that would be incredible.

Comment: `meanodba` are all `NA`, you also have issues with repeated values and one column is just `0` repeated.

Comment: @Baraliuh I updated the dataset...it's because the first 150ish lines don't have a meanodba value (due to no recording). But, those are taken out in the model anyway so it shouldn't matter. The precipitation and raining column also might look the same but this data set has over 11,000 rows so there are differing numbers throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't solve it (yet), but here's what I've tried so far.

Even when I take out the two variables that have no variability in the sample you gave us, and even when I simplify the problem by using `glm()` (without the random effect), I get an error:

(I called your data above `dd`)

```r
mf <- model.frame( meanodba ~ AirTemp + LagAir + Radiation +
                   Windspeed + LagRadiation + 
                   Precip + Raining + LULC + Elevation, dd)
bad <- sapply(mf, function(x) length(unique(x))==1)
glm1  <- glm(meanodba ~ .,
             data = mf[!bad],
             family = inverse.gaussian(link='inverse'))
```

> Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In sqrt((weights[good] * mu.eta.val[good]^2)/variance(mu)[good]) :
> NaNs produced

In this data set (`pairs(mf[!bad], gap = 0)`) the values for `LULC` and `Elevation` are very sparse (only two unique values, one of which is rare), but removing these two variables doesn't help either.

[image]

Fitting with `Gamma(link="log")` works, but `Gamma(link="inverse")` doesn't.  Switching to `inverse.gaussian(link="log")` doesn't work either ("Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size
In addition: Warning messages:
1: step size truncated due to divergence
2: step size truncated due to divergence")

I'm not surprised that the inverse link function is unstable/problematic, but I don't really understand why the inverse Gaussian would be.

Comment: Thank you for trying!! I hit up ChatGPT for help and they said this, "Possible causes for this error include:

Having a very large or very small value for a predictor in your data.
Having a column of constant values as predictor.
Having missing data in your dataset." which you and I have both tried to correct for. Where you actually able to get a model for Gamma with the log link? I'm wondering if I could potentially use that for the analysis.